# Show that the outer measure of a subset of Borel set is the measure of the Borel set.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets, borel-measures

For any subset $A ⊂ R^d$ (not necessarily measurable), show that there exists a
$G_δ$ set $G$ with $A ⊆ G$ and $m∗(A) = m(G).$

Here, $G_δ$ is a countable intersection of open sets. The outer measure associated to $m$ is defined for any set $A⊂ R^d$ by

$m_*(A)=inf \sum|Qj|$, with the infimum taken over all countable coverings, $A⊂\cup Q_j$ by closed cubes.

How does one go about proving this statement, given that $A$ is not necessarily measurable?

Comment: Hint: for each $n > 0$, take some countable covering $C_n$ such that $\sum |(C_n)_j| < m_*(a) + 1/n$.

Answer (score 0):

We can replace in the definitions closes cubes by open cubes. This is easy to see: Replace a covering of closed cubes $Q_j$ by an open covering $O_j$ such that $O_j$ is the interior of $Q_j$ scaled by a factor $f>1$ around the center of the cube (so you make the cube slightly larger by a factor $f$ to accomodate that border). Then the sum of the volumes of the cubes differs by a factor of $f^d$. By letting $f\to 1$ we thus get the same infimum.

Thus now take a sequence of open coverings $O_j^1,O_j^2,\ldots$ of $A$ so that
$$ \sum_j |O_j^i| \xrightarrow{i\to\infty} m_\ast(A) $$

Then we choose $G := \bigcap_i\bigcup_j O_j^i$. Then we have $A\subset G$ and $G$ is a $G_\delta$-set. Also by monotonity of $m_\ast$ we get
$$ m_\ast(A) \leq m_\ast(G) \leq m_\ast(\bigcup_j O_j^i) \leq \sum_j |O_j^i| $$
for all $i$, thus also for the infimum over all $i$. But as
$$ \inf_i\sum_j|O_j^i| = m_\ast(A)$$
we get
$$ m_\ast(A) = m_\ast(G)$$

Comment: I really like your proof, it's very elegant. One thing I am wondering about is why we can say with certainty that A ⊂ G ?

Comment: As $O_j^i$ are coverings of $A$ we have by definition of such a covering that $A\subset \bigcup_j O_j^i$. But since $A$ is a subset of each of these unions, it is also a subset of the intersection of these unions.